# Find the values of the constant p for which the series converges

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Find the values of the constant p for which the series

$$\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)(ln(ln(x)))^p}$$

converge. Fully justify your answer.

My attempt:

let $f(n) = a_n$

On $[3, \infty]$, $a_n$ clearly is positive.

(Lets assume I got the derivative and proved this series is decreasing)

Therefore the hypothesis of the integral test has been met.

## First Assume p = 1

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{3}^{n} \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(ln(ln(x)))}dx $$

Using $u = ln(x), du = \frac{1}{x} dx$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{ln(3)}^{ln(n)} \frac{1}{u \ln(u)} du$$

Using $v = ln(u)$ and $dv = \frac{1}{u} du$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{ln(ln(3))}^{ln(ln(n))} \frac{1}{v} dv$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} ln |v| \bigg|_{ln(ln(3))}^{ln(ln(n))}$$

$$=\infty$$

Therefore it diverges if p = 1.

## assume $p \neq 1$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{3}^{n} \frac{1}{x\ln(x)(ln(ln(x)))^p}dx $$

let $u = ln(x), du = \frac{1}{x} dx$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{ln(3)}^{ln(n)} \frac{1}{u(ln(u))^p}$$

let $v = ln(u), dv = \frac{1}{u} du$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{ln(ln(3))}^{ln(ln(n))} \frac{1}{v^p}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{v^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\bigg|_{ln(ln(3))}^{ln(ln(n))} = -\frac{1}{(-p+1)(ln(ln(3)))^{-p+1}}$$

This part I don't know what to say. I think this series converges for all p except 1? Also I'm not sure if my integrals are correct.

Comment: I haven't looked at the details, but you're on the right track. You missed an important point at the end though: What happens to $\ln(\ln(n))^{-p+1}$ as $n\to\infty$? Hint: It depends on the sign of $-p+1$.

Comment: $\infty^{-p+1}$, so if p > 1, then its 0 which converges. If p < 1, then it increaseswithout bound so it diverges?

Comment: Yes, that' right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all correct except at the very end. If $p<1$ the final limit is infinite. This should be expected: we already know the sequence does not converge for $p=1$, and so it clearly shouldn't converge for $p<1$, where term by term it is larger than for $p=1$. It does converge for every $p>1$.

Another good way to approach this problem is the [condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).